# How to publish a message from Firebase Functions V2 PubSub?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

The [docs for firebase functions v2](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/beta/pubsub-events)  includes information on how to listen to published messages however it doesn't show how to publish messages.

```
exports.hellopubsub = onMessagePublished("topic-name", (event) => {
  // ...
});
```

How do you publish messages from v2 pubsub functions without starting a separate nodejs server?

Comment: Have you checked the documentation of [Pub/Sub](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/publisher#publish_messages) ?

Comment: @Dharmaraj yes but I'm looking for a solution using firebase functions v2 pubsub feature (similar to how it works in v1) without importing `@google-cloud/pubsub`

Comment: Can you share a link to V1 version of what you are referring to?

Comment: I believe that just by implementing the code from pub/sub in you function should work to publish a [message](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/publisher#publish_messages). You can also adapt this [article](https://medium.com/@chandrapal/creating-a-cloud-function-to-publish-messages-to-pub-sub-154c2f472ca3) example to use CF v2, as basically the CF from Firebase are hosted in a GCP project and should work as a normal CF.